# In-app purchase got cancelled, but money debited from bank

Tags: google-play-store

Yesterday I was trying to make an in-app purchase (via netbanking as the payment option). After making the payment from the bank site, I was being returned to the app, when I was told "purchase cancelled". However, the money got deducted from my bank account. The transaction details in playstore web site shows that the purchase was "cancelled", and not "refunded". What do I need to do now to get my money back?

Please suggest.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about billing issues.  Please contact Google Play support and/or the app publisher and/or your bank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's banks payment error you get refund in around 6 days. Or later you can ask the developer for a refund. You can mail the developer to his email given in developer details